# How do I calculate the resonance frequency of a block of material?

Tags: frequency, resonance

I would like to know how I go about calculating the resonance frequency for an object, given its material properties and dimensions.
For example, a small rectangle $X$ by $Y$ by $Z$ dimensions, I would assume the material properties necessary are the Young's modules, $E$, and density, $\rho$.

And then how would this extend to other shaped objects?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the general case, you will use a finite element software such as Ansys to do a modal analysis of the object.  Young's modulus and E are the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware that Young's modulus and E are the same, I wrote it in the form of "parameter name, symbol" as is the general practise.

Comment: Oh, right!  Sorry I missed that.

Comment: That's no problem, thanks for trying to help. But outside of using finite element modelling tool, is there some back of the envelope calculations that you are aware of to calculate resonance for a block of material. I've got COMSOL and can plug parameters into that, but I am looking more for a way to compare or have an idea of the result before running the model, and to help improve my understanding of the physics involved.